# In a private container image instance on Azure, how and where are the image registry's password and username stored?

Tags: azure, security, containers, azure-container-instances

In a private container image instance on Azure, how and where are the image registry's password and username stored? Additionally, are the image registry  password and username compromised in the event of a container escape?

I'm trying to determine the security level of private container images hosted on Azure but I'm struggling to identify the specifics of the storage guarantee of the registry's username and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username and password of the Azure Container Registry are stored in the Key, you can find it like the screenshot below if you enable the admin user:
[image]

But if you want a safer user with appropriate permission, I suggest the service principal with the appropriate permission granted. For that, follow the steps [Azure Container Registry authentication with service principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal). The appropriate permission, for example, the user just need to pull the image, so it just needs the "acrpull" permission. All the permission you can find [here](https://github.com/Azure/acr/blob/master/docs/roles-and-permissions.md).

**Update**
When you log in the ACR, then the credentials will be stored in the docker config file under the home path like `~/.docker/config.json`. It will show you when you execute the CLI command `az acr login --name yourACR` like this:

[image]

Comment: I'm more so referencing the hosting of a private image from a repository or external registry via Azure Container Instance. In the creation of an Azure Container Instance of a private image, an external image URI or Docker Hub tag is requested along with the registry username and password -- what I'd like to know is how Microsoft store the username and password of the external registry of the private image.

Comment: @pntha OK, it stores in the docker config file under your home path like  `~/.docker/config.json`.

Comment: @pntha Any more questions? Or if it's helpful you can accept it.

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question